C++: fgets issue in getting command terminal data
I am writing a C++ program for an embedded Linux application for a custom device. Very often, I run Linux terminal commands via popen and pclose. If I need to only check whether the command was executed successfully or not, I check pclose return value. In other cases, if I need to check the terminal output for that command, I use fgets while the program is running. This has been working very well, until I stumbled with the following situation.
Now I need to write data to a flash memory, which is mapped to Linux kernel using MTD device driver. To write data to MTD, I need to first run flash_erase, and then nandwrite. These commands work fine if I run them manually on my device's console. Both these commands print out in the terminal information on the erasing/writing progress.
My C++ program must run both these commands to update the flash memory content. Also, my device has a GUI, and I want to gather progress information from these commands and show some sort of progress bar to the user.
The actual problem that I am facing now is that when I run nandwrite command, fgets gets stuck until the end of the execution. After the execution, it releases all previous terminal content at once. The same thing is not happening with any other command I run in the similar way, even flash_erase. With flash_erase, I am able to get partial output while the command is running and capture output and show it as percentage to the user on GUI.
Please check the following program. It is fully working, and it shows exactly the problem I just described.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool run_terminal_command(string cmd);
string get_timestamp();

int main() {
    run_terminal_command("flash_erase /dev/mtd4 0 188");
    run_terminal_command("nandwrite /dev/mtd4 flash_content.bin");
    return 0;
}

bool run_terminal_command(string cmd) {

    bool ret_val = false;

    cout << get_timestamp() << "running command: " << cmd << endl;

    FILE *process_handle = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");

    if (process_handle) {

        char buffer[256]{};

        cout << get_timestamp() << "just before loop ..." << endl;

        while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, process_handle)) {
            string line(buffer);
            line.erase(remove(line.begin(), line.end(), '\r'), line.end());
            line.erase(remove(line.begin(), line.end(), '\n'), line.end());
            cout << get_timestamp() << "this is from fgets: " << line << endl;
        }

        int res = pclose(process_handle);

        // check return from calling pclose itself
        if (res != -1) {
            // check return from the command, whether or not it exit status is zero
            if (WEXITSTATUS(res) == 0) {
                cout << get_timestamp() << "success" << endl << endl;
                ret_val = true;
            }
            else {
                cout << "WEXITSTATUS is not zero" << endl;
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "pclose error" << endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "process handle error" << endl;
    }

    return ret_val;
}

string get_timestamp() {

    auto now = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto tick_ms = chrono::time_point_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(now).time_since_epoch().count();
    std::time_t now_time_t = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
    std::tm now_tm = *localtime(&now_time_t);

    stringstream s_timestamp;

    s_timestamp << setw(2) << setfill('0') << now_tm.tm_hour;
    s_timestamp << ":";
    s_timestamp << setw(2) << setfill('0') << now_tm.tm_min;
    s_timestamp << ":";
    s_timestamp << setw(2) << setfill('0') << now_tm.tm_sec;
    s_timestamp << ".";
    s_timestamp << setw(3) << setfill('0') << (tick_ms % 1000);

    return ">>> [" + s_timestamp.str() + "] ";
}

The following is the output for the very same program above. Please note that some terminal information was ommited on purpose just for keeping it short.
In the flash_erase execuction, times keeps passing after the just before loop ... line.
But for nandwrite, there is a gap of 31 seconds between just before loop ... line and the first this is from fgets line. This 31 seconds represents the total time for running nandwrite with this specific file.
root@host:~# ./test_fgets 
>>> [11:34:38.177] running command: flash_erase /dev/mtd4 0 188
>>> [11:34:38.180] just before loop ...
>>> [11:34:38.318] this is from fgets: Erasing 4 Kibyte @ 0 *** ommited ***
>>> [11:34:38.432] this is from fgets: ing 4 Kibyte @ 6000 *** ommited ***
>>> [11:34:38.546] this is from fgets: g 4 Kibyte @ c000 --  *** ommited ***
>>> [11:34:38.660] *** ommited ***
>>> [11:34:41.566] this is from fgets: % complete Erasing 4 *** ommited ***
>>> [11:34:41.680] this is from fgets:  94 % complete Erasing 4 *** ommited ***
>>> [11:34:41.775] this is from fgets: 0 -- 97 % complete *** ommited ***
>>> [11:34:41.777] success

>>> [11:34:41.777] running command: nandwrite /dev/mtd4 flash_content.bin
>>> [11:34:41.779] just before loop ...
>>> [11:35:12.183] this is from fgets: Writing data to block 0 at offset 0x0
>>> [11:35:12.184] this is from fgets: Writing data to block 1 at offset 0x1000
>>> [11:35:12.184] this is from fgets: Writing data to block 2 at offset 0x2000
>>> [11:35:12.184] *** ommited ***
>>> [11:35:12.549] this is from fgets: Writing data to block 91 at offset 0x5b000
>>> [11:35:12.550] this is from fgets: Writing data to block 92 at offset 0x5c000
>>> [11:35:12.550] this is from fgets: Writing data to block 93 at offset 0x5d000
>>> [11:35:12.550] this is from fgets: Writing data to block 94 at offset 0x5e000
>>> [11:35:12.550] success

root@host:~#

Why is nandwrite releasing information to fgets all at once only at the end of the command?
I am running a custom distro built with Yocto project based on poky. The toolchain is also built from Yocto, based on arm-linux-gnueabi.
I would appreciate some guidance to understand better what is happening.
Thank you.
I have also tested other methods, like setting O_NONBLOCK flag via fcntl, using select and read instead of fgets, and even running the command with fork and execlp, but for all of them the behaviour is the same. When properly set, the non-blocking works does not block as exepected, however the terminal information is only available to read after the command is done. So I think it is not a blocking issue.

See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stdbuf.1.html

I saw stdbuf as a possible solution, but it is not available in my embedded system. I managed to make it work by using a pseudo terminal via posix_openpt. It is more complex because of fork and execlp, but it worked for me.

It turns out to be something related to buffering. Setting setvbuf to _IONBUF was not enough, so it worked by using pseuterminal via posix_openpt.
Here follows a version of my function adapted to work with pseuterminal. It is hardcoded for my nandwrite application. Argument parsing could be implemented though...
bool run_terminal_nandwrite(string filepath) {

bool ret_val = false;

char buffer[256]{};

int main_fd;
char name[100];
main_fd = posix_openpt(O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
if (main_fd == -1) {
    cout << "error: posix_openpt" << endl;
}
else if (grantpt(main_fd) == -1 || unlockpt(main_fd) == -1) {
    cout << "error: grantpt/unlockpt" << endl;
}
else if (ptsname_r(main_fd, name, sizeof(name)) != 0) {
    cout << "error: ptsname_r" << endl;
}
else {
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1) {
        cout << "error: fork" << endl;
    }
    else if (pid == 0) {
        // child process
        int child_fd = open(name, O_RDWR);
        if (child_fd == -1) {
            cout << "error: open child" << endl;
        }
        else {
            dup2(child_fd, STDIN_FILENO);
            dup2(child_fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
            dup2(child_fd, STDERR_FILENO);
            close(child_fd);
            execlp("/usr/sbin/nandwrite",
                   "nandwrite",
                   "/dev/mtd4",
                   filepath.c_str(),
                   (char *) NULL);
            cout << "error: execlp" << endl;
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    else {
        // parent process
        struct pollfd fds;
        fds.fd = main_fd;
        fds.events = POLLIN;
        int status;

        while (true) {

            int ret = poll(&fds, 1, 1000);
            if (ret == -1) {
                cout << "error: poll" << endl;
                break;
            }
            else if (ret == 0) {
                // timeout
                continue;
            }
            else if (fds.revents & POLLIN) {
                ssize_t bytes = read(main_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1);
                if (bytes > 0) {
                    string line(buffer);
                    line.erase(remove(line.begin(), line.end(), '\r'), line.end());
                    line.erase(remove(line.begin(), line.end(), '\n'), line.end());
                    cout << get_timestamp() << "this is from fgets: " << line << endl;
                }
                else if (bytes == 0) {
                    // end of process
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    cout << "error: read" << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }

            pid_t child_result = waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG);

            if (child_result == 0) {
                // child still running
            }
            else if (child_result == -1) {
                // child error
                cout << "error: waitpid" << endl;
                break;
            }
            else {
                // child has exited
                if (WEXITSTATUS(status) == 0) {
                    cout << get_timestamp() << "success" << endl << endl;
                    ret_val = true;
                }
                else {
                    cout << "error: WEXITSTATUS" << endl;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

return ret_val;

}

The basic problem you have is that fgets reads data until it gets a newline, and waits until it sees a newline.
Your nandwrite/flasherase programs are writing text without newlines -- each line of info is written and then backspaces or carriage returns are used to back up over the line and rewrite the same screen line when the output goes to a terminal.
When you use popen and fgets, this means that that it looks like all the data is coming at once at the end, since that is the only time a newline is printed.
If you used fread or fgetc instead of fgets, this "wait for a newline" would not occur, and you would see the data as it is output.  You could also use fileno + read to read the file descriptor directly (and even do non-blocking reads, so you can see eaxactly when data is available).

flash_erase does just as you pointed out: it makes a carrier return. fgets returns periodically, though.
But nandwrite actually sends line by line. I can see it if I run it manually on a terminal. Also, I checked that out. If I print the hex content of the strings at the end of the execution, each line has the linefeed (0x0a) char.

I have done another test: fgets for nandwrite is not returning only at the end of the execution. Actually, fgets releases a bunch of lines about every 30 seconds. First I thought fgets would return only at the end of the execution because the file I was using for testing takes about 30 secods to write. After that, I tried with a larger file that would take like 3 minutes, and from time to time, I managed to get some lines from fgets. That's why I think the issue is related to buffering.

fgets will also return when the buffer is full, so if the program runs for awhile continuously outputting text without newlines, that is what you see.  If you instead use fgetc to read characters in a loop, you'll get them as soon as they are output by the program, without having to wait for newlines.

I have tried both fileno + read and fgetc. These two also keep blocking.

This characterisation of fgets() is not quite correct.   The second argument of fgets(), often named count, is the size of the buffer being read to.   fgets() will never read more than count - 1 bytes from the stream (the -1 allowing for appending a trailing '\0').  The net effect is that fgets() will stop if count - 1 characters OR a newline have been read.   The only circumstance in which fgets() will wait is if the stream buffer contains no (pending/buffered) characters at all - presence or absence of a newline does not change that.
